# Is there a way to prevent responsive bootstrap from taking too much width?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I would like to use the responsive features of bootstrap, but not for layouts > 1200px.

On devices with a width > 1200px, it should act as for the device size just under.

Is this possible to tune the meta viewport or add some css so the maximum device width is 1200px ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Customize Bootstrap**
The best way is to download a customized version according to your needs . The page below will take you to customize page and there you can deselect Large Desktop in responsive section

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html

And it will reduce all the hassle of writing queries and removing chunks from css manually.

Comment: Didn't know the bootstrap customization form allowed to choose wich media queries to use, cheers !

Comment: Happy coding !Let me know if ya need more help

Answer (score 1):

What happens for viewpoints > 1200 px is all defined in your CSS.

Is there anything for stopping you from editing the CSS file and either removing the entire block

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {  
.......
}
```

or changing it to somehing that will never happen like

```
@media (min-width: 12000px) {
....
}
```

**Update**

Have you considered using the default Bootstrap grid (with non-fluid rows)? There's an example at http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/hero.html

The behaviour is very similar to what you would get if you remove >1200 media requests from the responsive CSS.

Here are a couple of CDN sources for the non-responsive CSS:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css (v2.3)

and
http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap.min.css (v2.2)

Good luck!

Comment: I'm hotlinking twitter bootstrap at the moment, but this might be a solution, indeed.