# Prevent Twitter responsive layout from collapsing when width < 320px

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Example: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/carousel.html

I want the responsive layout stop collapsing when the width < 320px, i.e. show a horizontal scroll bar instead if width is < 320px.

What is the best way to set this `min-width`?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121417/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-responsive-bootstrap-from-taking-too-much-width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in bootstrap for:

```
@media (min-width: 320px) {  

}
```

and change to whatever you want to happen.